# Preview App gets crashed

Tags: macos, preview.app

I have Macbook with 8Gb RAM. I have two folders with 1000 images each. The size of both the folders is around 25 MB each. I have to make some comparisons, therefore, I have to open the images of both the folders simultaneously in two windows.

**PROBLEM:** When I open the contents of both the folders in two windows (I am using the option: ***open Groups of files in the same window***), either the Preview app crashes or my MacBook gets hang after sometime and as soon as I close these two windows, everything becomes fine.

**IMPORTANT:** I even tried to close all the running apps. But if I open a single app like google chrome (with only single google homepage window), Macbook hangs. I checked the RAM usage and it says that I am using 6.59 GB out of 8 GB.

Answer (score 0):

JPG is a compressed file format. Once the computer has to decompress that to display on screen, the memory requirement may go up by a huge factor.

A guess would be that Preview is trying to decompress the whole lot in one go to keep in RAM & you simply run out of memory & start paging so hard that everything essentially grinds to a halt.
8GB RAM is really not a lot these days, if this is the kind of task you need to do frequently.

A workaround might be to use something like [ViewIt](http://www.hexcat.com/viewit/index.html) [paid app £15 but there is a freeware Lite version] which is designed for large libraries & doesn't try to decompress all at once.

Comment: I actually don't need to open all the images altogether. I just need to compare the images of one folder to the images of another folder one by one. In windows/linux, only one image of the folder can be opened and then you can navigate to other images using arrows keys. In that way, you don't need to open all the images together. Can something like that be possible?

Comment: You could do that with Quick Look. Select a picture, hit Spacebar. Navigate the hierarchy using the arrow keys

Comment: I already tried that. But as I mentioned that I need to open the images from TWO FOLDERS and compare them by keeping them open side by side so, as soon as I click on the image from second folder, the Quick look shows that image and hence the first image is not visible any more.

Comment: Then it's back to ViewIt, as originally mentioned